# May one say "a question of profound principle"?

Tags: phrase-request, expressions, idiom-request

Does the expression  "a question of profound principle" sound idiomatic enough? Is it tolerable? I am not sure, because Google does not give many references. I'm happy with the meaning, but if it sounds bad... Would "fundamental" be better?

Comment: Yes, although I'm not sure I'd use the adjective "profound" with "principle".  But that's more personal style than grammar rule.  In any case this question is likely to be removed unless you provide some more detail why you think this is inappropriate, what you want to say, and possibly what other words you might choose instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As with many dictionary definitions](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/profound), "profound" has many *meanings* that can't be applied just anywhere.  For example one definition is "very strongly felt" or "very great" as in:

> The candidate's speech profoundly moved her.

This means that the speech affected her in a *deep* and *significant* way, that it possibly "changed her life".  So you might think that a "profound principle" is a guideline or rule that similarly affects someone's life in a deep or significant way.

The challenge is that a principle is just a guide or a rule, and I would say that *by itself* it can't be "profound".  It can have a profound *effect*, yes, or a profound *impact*, or various other combinations, but profound principle doesn't quite work for me.

There is the other definition of profound: "having or showing great knowledge or understanding" -- but does this really apply to a *principle*?  I would say it's more suited to something like a *philosophy*, or an *insight*, or a *theory*, or a *work of art*, or similar.

If you want to say that the principle is the basis for other principles or ethics, then *fundamental* seems more appropriate, although unfortunately it doesn't have that nice [alliteration](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/alliteration).

Still, as I said in my comment, this is more personal preference than grammar.  I admit I could be wrong.

Comment: I have suddenly doubted. Is it clear that "a question of profound principle" = ""a question that is a matter of principle and very much so""?

Comment: @Serguei  A "matter of principle" means that you will (or won't) to something not because it's convenient or beneficial to you but because it's  something you **strongly** believe.  "Profound" doesn't really imply "even more so" -- for that you can use something like "deep, personal principle".  But then again you can say you have a "profound religious belief" so it's possible I'm wrong.

Comment: One last question. I like "deep" much more than "profound". How  does "a question of deep principle" sound to you? Is it too bizarre?

Comment: @Serguei Again I would say "deep personal principle" or "deep philosophical principle" or "deep religious principle" or some other flavor of principle.  But in this case "profound" works just fine.